# Laravel Gettext Error Class 'App\Http\Controllers\LaravelGettext' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, gettext

I followed these steps for installing Gettext with laravel

https://github.com/Belphemur/laravel-gettext

However, I am getting Class 'App\Http\Controllers\LaravelGettext' not found
error.

If I include the namespace with classes, it says, that the method is not defined as static, which is true after checking the code.

Am I missing something?

Error place (copied from the gettext plugin page)

```
public function changeLang($locale=null) {

    LaravelGettext::setLocale($locale);
    return Redirect::to(URL::previous());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to add `use Path\to\LaravelGettext;` at the top of your file outside the class.

I am not sure what's the path to LaravelGettext. Maybe it is `Xinax\LaravelGettext\Facades\LaravelGettext`

Comment: Thank you so much!  "Facades" was the folder I was missing. Addressing the class directly didn't work.